# Can the possible forms of f(z) be deduced from the following equation and accompanying assumptions only?

Tags: complex-analysis

$\int \frac{f(z)}{z} dz = 0$ (over any closed contour in $\mathbb{C}$) , given that $f(z)$ is bounded and entire.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is bounded and entire implies that $f$ is a constant. By assumption if $\gamma$ is some simple closed contour containing $0$, then Cauchy Integral Formula implies $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z}dz=f(0)$$
which shows $f=0$ everywhere